# How to insert variable in PHP Passing ID in href

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have code to passing ID in href in the below :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app_summary/hoplist/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="large-box">
```

with my link href code in above, i want to insert these variable :

```
$first = '2018/01/20';
$end = '2018/01/25';
```

how to insert varibles above into my PHP passing ID in href?

thanks for advice...

Comment: what do you mean? can u re explain this clearly?

Comment: i really dont know what do you mean. How if you post what output/result did you expect?

Comment: Can you provide a sample url structure you expect to see when the values are passed ?

Comment: @plonknimbuzz i used link href to show data detail that i choose from rows, so i used passing href id to show detail (same with condition with show edit form) to spesific which data that i want to process. But in my detail view i want to used `$first` and `$end` to give date information in detail view...

Comment: @Tyas: bentuk output nya gmn, bukan penjelasannya. makin baca makin punyeng gw wkkw. soalnya href kagak pnya id, yg ada itu anchor. misal: output yg di pengen `<a href="http://localhost/app_summary/hoplost/12/blabla" id="myanchor" class="myclass">mytext</a>` (english: please provide your expected result not your explainationbecause href is properties and it dont have an id)

Comment: @plonknimbuzz mungkin maksudnya di link berikutnya dia pingin bawa variable tambahan, cuma gimana caranya, mungkin ada alternatif solusi..
English : maybe she means that in the next view (detail) she need to used date, but she confused how to declare, maybe you have alternative solution..

Comment: @karisma: i see. ty

Comment: @plonknimbuzz do you have any solution? (: if you have please write in answer, then i will try, hehe thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('app_summary/hoplist/'.$row['id'].'/'.$first.'/'.$end);?>" class="large-box">
```

then in your controller (to show detail) you can separate `$first` and `$end` with `$this->uri->segment()` like this :

```
  $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $frsdate = $this->uri->segment(4);
  $enddate = $this->uri->segment(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$first = '2018/01/20';

$end = '2018/01/25';

$first = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($first));

$end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end));

<a href="<?php echo base_url('app_summary/hoplist/'.$row['id'].'/'.$first.'/'.$end);?>" class="large-box">
```

you can Try like this ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where you intend to include those variables, but this is how I would do it, of course adjusting for your situation.

```
<?php echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'app_summary/hoplist/' . $row['id'] . $code . $matrix . date("m/d/Y") . 'class="large-box">'; ?>
```

edit to show date in example.

Comment: sorry, i changed my varibles, how if my variable is date? is it same method with your code above?

Comment: Sure if you like. Any variable make sure they follow the same format.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="<?=base_url('app_summary/hoplist/'.$row['id'] .'/code='. urlencode($code). '/matrix='.urlencode($matrix));?>" class="large-box">
```

or using http_build_query

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'code' => '2018/01/20',
    'matrix' => $matrix,
    'other' => 'some text with space'
);

?>

<a href="<?=base_url('app_summary/hoplist/'.$row['id'] .'/'. http_build_query($data));?>" class="large-box">
```